# Why am I getting the message "connection refused" after port forwarding correctly?

Tags: router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

I'm trying to port forward the port 25565 (for a minecraft server, doesn't have anything to do with the issue as far as I'm aware). Currently, I am able to connect to the server on any device on the same network as me, however friends from other networks cannot join. I think this is because there is an issue with the port forwarding I've done. I've used websites like canyouseeme.org, and I receive the error "Connection refused."

I'm pretty certain that the port is forwarded correctly. I did it for my IP address, on TCP and UDP, and after calling the company that produces my router, (eero) the representative said that I had successfully forwarded the port.

What think I've managed to figure out is that the issue comes from a firewall. I completely (temporarily) turned off Windows Defender's Firewall, which made the error change from "timed out" to "refused." The security measures on my router have been temporarily turned off, too, and it didn't seem to do anything. I've heard that performing a DMZ will be able to solve this issue, but unfortunately eero does not support this.

I've also heard that an issue can come from the port not listening at all, but if I'm using canyouseeme.org, shouldn't that make the port listen?

Comment: well first off, a port listens on the server, because a process has opened that port and is paying attention for traffic coming in on it. you can check on windows in an elevated powershell prompt by running `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING` and looking for a line with your port number. if there isn't one, or its listening on 127.0.0.1, the port is not listening and nothing you do will work. Next check the firewall on the router. Many routers will automatically allow traffic when you forward a port, but make sure that it is the case for your model.

Comment: also note that many ISPs block higher ports, so you may do better trying a 4-digit port number if you have control of the ports on the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the forwarding is ok and you can connect from your local lan i will suggest you to check if something is blocked from your internet provider( free firewall service ) or your provider is not actually giving you an internet ip ( to save on giving ip they put you behind NAT )